# Al devolver un status 404 en una página y volverla a republicar, afecta en la indexacion de google?

Tags: seo, jobs

mi pregunta recae en que si republico una URL que estaba devolviendo un status 404, google vuelve a tomar la antigua indexacion que tenia de esa URL con su nivel de autoridad o se volveria a reiniciar la indexacion como si de una URL nueva se tratase?

Se que esto puede parecer algo insignificante, pero agradecería encarecidamente que me respondieran si alguien sabe la respuesta.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Leyendo las respuestas anteriores no me queda claro como trataría Google una URL que anteriormnte fue marcada como 404 porque el contenido expiró pero que es republicada. La contará como una nueva URL o mantendrá la autoridad que tenía antes de la expiración y del 404? Muchas gracias!

Comment: @CarlosValcárcelCobo creo que es claro lo que dice Google: *La mayoría de los errores 404 no afectan a la clasificación de tu sitio web en Google, por lo que puedes ignorarlos tranquilamente. Estos mensajes de error se suelen deber a errores ortotipográficos, a configuraciones incorrectas o a los crecientes esfuerzos de Google por reconocer y rastrear enlaces en contenido insertado (por ejemplo, JavaScript).* Ni la cuenta como una nueva URL, ni la autoridad de la página se ve afectada. Un error 404 no tiene ningún impacto con respecto a Google, pero sí con respecto al usuario (mala UX).

Answer (score 4):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Los errores 404 no afectan ni a tu sitio ni a esa URL en particular, porque Google reconoce que ese error puede deberse a una situación (temporal o definitiva) **que no depende necesariamente de ti**, por lo tanto no es justo que seas penalizado por ello y de hecho Google no te penaliza. De ser así, imagina las posibles triquiñuelas que podría hacer la competencia de un sitio web para hacer caer en ranking a su rival. Imagina millones de boots creando y difundiendo millones de *fake* URLs sobre el sitio rival en cualquier área.

Un escenario muy simple es que alguien que no eres tú haga referencia a tu sitio y cometa algún error escribiendo la URL, o que alguien simplemente desde la barra de navegación intente buscar cosas que no existen (estoy es muy frecuente en páginas que usan URLs como: `dominio.com/recurso/1`, `dominio.com/recurso/2`  ... supongamos que un usuario diga: *vamos a ver lo que hay en el recurso `3`*, y escribe esto: `dominio.com/recurso/3`, pero tú, por falta de tiempo no has escrito el recurso `3`, estarás teniendo un error 404 involuntario.

Por eso y por muchos otros motivos los errores 404 no tienen ningún peso en cuanto al ranking o autoridad de tu sitio.

Eso no significa que haya que ignorarlos, no. Es tu responsabilidad, corregir de tu lado cualquier posibilidad de error 404 que haya y hacer redirecciones en contenido antiguo que ya no exista.

Google tampoco retira una URL porque dé error 404. Para retirar la URL tienes que quitarla de `robots.txt` o indicar a Google que quieres borrarla a través de la herramienta adecuada en WebMasters Tools.

Finalmente, te dejo la [última información de Google sobre los errores 404](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35120?hl=es):

> #### Corregir los errores 404
>
> La mayoría de los errores 404 no afectan a la clasificación de tu sitio web en Google, por lo que puedes ignorarlos tranquilamente. Estos mensajes de error se suelen deber a
>   errores ortotipográficos, a configuraciones incorrectas o a los
>   crecientes esfuerzos de Google por reconocer y rastrear enlaces en
>   contenido insertado (por ejemplo, JavaScript). A continuación te
>   indicamos algunas cuestiones que te ayudarán a investigar y corregir
>   errores 404:
>
> 1. **Decide si vale la pena.**
>
> Muchos, si no la mayoría, de los errores 404 no son tan importantes
>   como para que valga la pena corregirlos. Ordena los errores 404 por
>   prioridad y corrige los que realmente debas solucionar. Puedes pasar
>   por alto los demás, ya que este tipo de error no perjudica ni al
>   índice ni al posicionamiento de tu sitio web. A continuación, te
>   mostramos los motivos por los que no es necesario corregirlos todos:
>
> - Si se trata de una página eliminada que no tiene reemplazo ni equivalente, debe devolverse un error 404.
> - Si se trata de una URL incorrecta generada por una secuencia de comandos o que nunca ha existido en tu sitio web, es muy probable que
>     no debas preocuparte por ello. Puede que te moleste verla en el
>     informe, pero no es necesario corregirla, salvo si se trata de un
>     enlace que se escribe incorrectamente con frecuencia. A continuación
>     tienes más información al respecto.
>
> 2.**Consulta de dónde provienen los enlaces no válidos.**
>
> Haz clic en una URL para ver de dónde provienen los enlaces de estas
>   páginas. En función de si el enlace está en tu sitio web o en un sitio
>   web de terceros, debes seguir estos pasos:
>
> **a.** Corrige los enlaces que provienen de tu sitio web y que dirigen a páginas que no existen, o bien elimínalos si procede.
>
> - Si el contenido se ha movido, añade una URL de redireccionamiento.
> - Si has eliminado el contenido de forma permanente sin la intención de reemplazarlo por contenido relacionado y más reciente, deja que la
>     antigua URL devuelva un error 404 o 410. Actualmente, Google trata los
>     errores 410 (No disponible permanentemente) del mismo modo que los 404
>     (Página no encontrada). El hecho de devolver un código distinto al 404
>     o al 410 para una página inexistente (o de redireccionar a los
>     usuarios a otra página, como a la página principal, en lugar de
>     devolver un código 404) puede suponer un problema. Estas páginas se
>     conocen como errores 404 leves y pueden confundir tanto a los usuarios
>     como a los motores de búsqueda.
> - Si la URL es desconocida, es posible que veas puntualmente errores 404 de direcciones URL que nunca han existido en tu sitio web. El
>     robot de Google podría generar estas URL inesperadas al seguir enlaces
>     en JavaScript, en archivos Flash o en otro tipo de contenido insertado
>     o que posiblemente solo existe en un sitemap. Por ejemplo, es posible
>     que tu sitio web utilice un código parecido al siguiente para realizar
>     un seguimiento de las descargas de archivos en Google Analytics:
>
>   ```
>   <a href="helloworld.pdf"
>     onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/download-helloworld']);">
>     Hello World PDF</a>
>   ```
>
>   Cuando el robot de Google vea ese código, es posible que intente rastrear la URL http://www.example.com/download-helloworld, aunque no
>     sea una página real. En ese caso, el enlace puede mostrarse como un
>     error 404 (página no encontrada) en el informe Errores de rastreo.
>     Google está trabajando para evitar este tipo de error de rastreo, que
>     no tiene ningún efecto sobre el rastreo ni la clasificación de tu
>     sitio web.
>
> **b.** Corrige los enlaces mal escritos en otros sitios con redireccionamientos 301. Por ejemplo, el hecho de escribir como
>   (www.example.com/sapatosrojos la URL auténtica
>   www.example.com/zapatosrojos) probablemente se deba a que alguien ha
>   enlazado con tu sitio web y ha cometido una falta de ortografía. En
>   este caso, se puede capturar la URL mal escrita si se crea una
>   redirección 301 a la URL correcta. También puedes ponerte en contacto
>   con el webmaster del sitio web con el enlace incorrecto y pedirle que
>   lo modifique o lo retire.
>
> 3. **Ignora el resto de errores.**
>
> No crees contenido falso ni redirijas desde tu página principal, ni
>   uses un archivo robot.txt para bloquear estas URL, puesto que todas
>   estas opciones dificultan el reconocimiento y el correcto
>   procesamiento de la estructura de tu sitio web. Estos errores se
>   conocen como errores 404 leves. Ten en cuenta que, al hacer clic en
>   Este problema está corregido en el informe Errores de rastreo solo se
>   oculta temporalmente el error 404, que se mostrará de nuevo cada vez
>   que Google intente rastrear la URL.Una vez que Google haya rastreado
>   una URL correctamente, puede que intente hacerlo de forma indefinida.
>   Al crear un redireccionamiento del tipo 300, se retrasará el intento
>   para volver a rastrear, posiblemente durante mucho tiempo.  Ten en
>   cuenta que enviar una solicitud de eliminación de URL mediante la
>   herramienta correspondiente no eliminará el error de este informe.
>
> Si no reconoces una URL de tu sitio web, puedes ignorarla. Estos
>   errores suceden cuando alguien navega a una URL que no existe en tu
>   sitio web; puede que alguien escribiera incorrectamente una URL en el
>   navegador o que la URL del enlace estuviera mal escrita. Sin embargo,
>   es posible que te interese descubrir alguna de estas URL mal escritas
>   como se describe en la lista anterior.

Comment: el caso que se me presenta son ofertas que tenia publicadas que ahora han expirado y google las trata como soft 404, aunque ya no se pueda aplicar a esa oferta, la pagina sigue teniendo contenido de valor para el usuario ya que ofrece una lista de ofertas parecidas. Que solución crees que sería mejor, dar un status 404 para esas ofertas expiradas y perder el contenido de valor o ignorar los soft 404 de search console que da google. Me he fijado que el numero de ofertas indexadas ha bajado tal y como suben los soft 404, y esto no deberia ser asi ya que cada día publicamos ofertas.

Comment: @user9308728 la respuesta da varias ideas sobre como proceder. Según tu contexto puedes crear lo que yo llamaría una *Política de Redirecciones*  en tu sitio, donde rediriges esa viejas a ofertas por ejemplo a su página principal de categorías, o a una página de las últimas ofertas, etc. Aunque claro, si hay miles de páginas así habría que pensar en algo más sofisticado como manejarlo a nivel de una base de datos...o cambiar la forma en que presentas contenido temporal en tu sitio, puedes crear un sistema de redirecciones internos usando por ejemplo PHP, algo sí como un patrón `MVC`...

Comment: El problema es que estas páginas que contienen las ofertas expiradas, tienen contenido bastante útil para el usuario (una lista con ofertas parecidas en la plataforma) y no queremos redireccionarlas ni dar un error 404. Como podría hacer para que google vea estas páginas como una sección con contenido diferente al de una oferta y no solo como una oferta expirada a la cual ya no se puede aplicar, o simplemente que no las intente indexar? Con la etiqueta noindex debería bastar? La he añadido recientemente pero parece no surtir ningún efecto. De nuevo gracias de antemano!

Comment: @user9308728 lo que planteas es muy interesante, pero me parece que es objeto de otra pregunta... No es tan fácil de responder, y menos a través de comentarios. No he investigado sobre eso, pero puede que la documentación de Google o de otros sitios expertos arrojen pistas sobre cómo afrontar datos como esos.